# Join sales/order and ordered items in grid column render Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-grid, items

I created a custom column in **sales/order** grid named Product name, They are coming fine on first time, When I am doing sorting Found :

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_name' in 'order clause'
```

And find there is need to join ordered items also, Here is my code:

```
     $joinTable2 =$this->getTable('customer_entity_varchar');
    $this->getSelect()->join($joinTable2. ' as fn', 'main_table.customer_id = fn.entity_id and fn.attribute_id = 177',array('value'));
return $this;
```

Please suggest if anyone have solution, Thanks in advance.